# changing name of x-axis for avplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `avplot` in rStudio I created an Added Variable Plot.

I tried to change the name of the x-axis of the separate plots but can't figure out how to change them separately (so that every plot has the correct labelling of the x-axis).

Using `xlab` I could only change all of them at the same time with the same name.

My goal is to change the `df$bis11_survey.Attention` into "Attention" and so on.
I don't want to rename them in the data frame, only in the plot if thats's possible.

I added a screenshot of the plot
[image]

What command could I use that would let me change them separately?

Comment: Could you please edit this question to include sample data and code used to generate the plots?

Comment: This doesn't look like it is produced with [tag:ggplot2], more likely base graphics, are you intentionally asking for a ggplot2-version of this plot? Regardless ... as jpsmith said, reproducibility is too important for this kind of question, with no data we cannot play, and with no code we have no idea what you are using. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.